# Email submissions getting through with blank required fields

Tags: solspace-freeform

We have a Contact Form for a client that is somehow allowing users to submit it with blank fields that are set to be required. Submissions appear to be from valid sources...aka not spam. When we attempt to test it on multiple devices, operating systems, and browsers, **ALL** validation works as expected.

ExpressionEngine Version: 2.9.2
Freeform Version: 4.2.2

Here is an example of the form showing errors for blank fields.

[image: Image showing validation working]

Here is the backend of Freeform showing a couple of submissions that have gotten through with blank fields.

[image: Freeform submissions with blank fields]

If we could recreate the situation we believe we could fix it. Unfortunately, everything we tried, the system works as expected.

Has anyone had a similar experience? If yes, did you find a solution solution?

Comment: Is it JavaScript dependant or validated on the backend?

Comment: did you specify the required fields in the "required=" parameter? Is this a composer form or built out in the template?

Comment: Form is built out in the template. "required=" parameter is set. We turned off JS in several browsers and still couldn't replicate the issue, so not dependent. Should be validated server side.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, don't have enough rep points to comment, but I also just had this issue. It's a multi-page Composer Form and has been working for over a year. Yesterday a submission came through where most of the required fields were blank. Did you figure out what was going on by any chance?

Comment: No solution at this point.